# Opening large data URLs in Chrome

Tags: javascript, base64

I have this JS code:

```
link.href = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + data;
```

where `data` is base64 string. The link opens properly in Firefox, but not in Chrome when size of PDF file is huge (> 1.5MB).

Why doesn't this work? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't allow opening data URLs for security reasons. You might be able to open the link using "Open in new tab" (right click menu).

As a work around, if possible, you can force the user to download the file using `<a download="example.pdf"  href= data:URL >`

Or try using **blob:URL** instead of **data:URL**. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript) might help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This solution works in chrome when size of pdf file is less than 1.5 MB and this open in new tab option also does not work. I guess there is limitation in number of characters in URL in chrome which is preventing pdf from getting loaded.